# Capybara::ExpectationNotMet, link is not appropriate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, capybara

I've got Rspec/Capybara tests for my Rails 3 application.

One of the tests started to fail:

```
it { should have_link(I18n.t('ui.delete'), href: user_path(User.last)) }
```

And this is an output error:

```
1) User pages index delete links as an admin user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link(I18n.t('ui.delete'), href: user_path(User.last)) }
 Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
   expected to find link "o'chirish (delete)" but there were no matches. 
Also found   "o'chirish (delete)", "o'chirish (delete)",
"o'chirish (delete)", "o'chirish (delete)", "o'chirish (delete)", "o'chirish (delete)", 
"o'chirish (delete)", "o'chirish (delete)", 
which matched the selector but not all filters.
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:158:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

On my web page, the links look ok (each *o'chirish (delete)* has a delete link)

```
1 admin admin admin@gmail.com | admin  
6 author author author@gmail.com | author | o'chirish (delete)  
5 editorxxx editor editor@gmail.com | editor | o'chirish (delete)  
9 home page user1@gmail.com | o'chirish (delete)  
10 taken tekken user22@gmail.com | o'chirish (delete)  
8 tester tester2 tester@gmail.com | o'chirish (delete)  
7 user user user@gmail.com | o'chirish (delete)
```

Thank you very much for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that message in two cases as far as I remember: The link is there, but not visible (`display:none;`) or the `href` is not the same. Since you said that you can see the link you should check whether the `href` is set correctly.